# Android - achartengine annotation rotation

Tags: android, annotations, achartengine

How to rotate annotations on bar chart 90 degrees? I want to set annotations with horizantal BarChart from left to right opposed to top-down.

The numbers are chartvalues but I want to rotate annotations "annot", "test" added by AddAnnotation(annotation,x,y) method.

[image: Sample Screnshot for Annotations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have edit library code.

Change in `BarChart.java` in method `drawChartValuesText()` .

Make 0 to 90.

```
 if (value >= 0) {
          drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), value), x, points.get(i + 1)
              - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 90);
        } else {
          drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), value), x, points.get(i + 1)
              + renderer.getChartValuesTextSize() + renderer.getChartValuesSpacing() - 3, paint, 90);
        }
```

For Annotation change this in draw() of `XYChart.java`

```
drawString(canvas, series.getAnnotationAt(j), xS, yS, paint);
```

to

```
 drawText(canvas, series.getAnnotationAt(j), xS, yS, paint,90);
```

Comment: No just make these changes and make it jar again.

Comment: So instead of a jar I need to use aChartEngine as Android Library project. But I guess source code is read only on svn. "# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://achartengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ achartengine-read-only"  edit: Oh I see.

Comment: Thanks to this refactor and orginal source I was able to extend BarChart to make the changes tou suggested. Sadly it turns the values of the bars not annotations.

Comment: What do u mean by annotation ? can u show some image ?

Comment: I will add some images when I have my hands on source again in weekdays. Basically annotations allows you to put any string to any x,y value on the chart. addAnnotation method on XYSeries.http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/XYSeries.html#addAnnotation(java.lang.String, double, double)

Comment: Edited the question with screenshots

Comment: @mozgek See the changes in my answer and thanks for ur help to understand annotations.

Comment: So thank you. I'll accept this as an answer since it seems there is no out of the box solution :) But the refactor must be an old version because it's missing come annotation proporties. Anyway this will work. Thank you

Comment: @mozgek did u got latest code of achartengine? that is 1.1.0?

Comment: @Monicka Actually I did not. We have changed the tactic and used native android view elements to build our chart. The answer is still valid I guess but I'm no more using it.